# Liquibase integration with VSTS(Visual studio online) TFS

Tags: liquibase, azure-pipelines

I am looking for liquibase db refactoring tool integration with CI - vsts visual studio team services) tfs. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Do you solve this issue with batch file task?

Comment: Yes I am able to solve this issue with batch filr.

Comment: It would be appreciated if you share your command lines

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which CI tool you are using, but every one I can think of supports running tools from a command line. Liquibase has a command line interface. That is how I would suggest you start.

Comment: Thanks ! I am using vsts(visual studio online) as ci tool . I am thinking of calling batch file from ci tool to use liquibase . Let me know if this is correct approach as I can see no task/plugin is available in vsts for liquibase.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is call script through Command Line/Batch Script task.

You also can [custom build/release task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task) to do work with liquibase.

Comment: I have created batch file and will be calling it in vsts batch file task. Hope this is correct approach. Thank You .